# ACF Image in Repeater not working

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

For a custom WP theme I am creating I am using ACF. I need to have a repeater that outputs images. I have it set to image object and using the correct code. In fact I tried it without a repeater and it works perfectly. Its only within the repeater that it fails.

```
                <div class="row col-md-12">
                <?php

                // check if the repeater field has rows of data
                if( have_rows('pics') ):

                    // loop through the rows of data
                    while ( have_rows('pics') ) : the_row();

                        // display a sub field value
                ?><div class="col-md-4">

                    <?php 

                    $image = get_field('img');

                    if( !empty($image) ): ?>

                        <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div> <?

                    endwhile;

                else :

                    // no rows found

                endif;

                ?>
            </div>
```

What is causing the image data to not loop?

Comment: Also for the img tag "echo $image['url'];" does not fix the problem either.

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks ok, but having checked how I did it I believe you should be using `get_sub_field` instead of `get_field`

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/

Your comment about using the ['url'] part of the array is also relevant. This is working for me;

```
    $image = get_sub_field('img');

    if( !empty($image) ): ?>

        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you have to do:

```
<?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('img') ):

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('img') ) : the_row();

        // display a sub field value
        $image = get_sub_field('sub_img'); ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
    <?php endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;

?>
```

This is assuming that you are outputting an image object and not a url in your ACF settings.